# ticks show up as 100μ in stead of 0.0001

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using plotly JS to create a chart.
All is well, accept for the ticks and the hovers. 
I have a range of numbers and they are turned into something else by plotly.

Per example: 0.0001 will be shown as 100μ 
And what I actually want is this to be shown as or 0.0001 or as 1/10000

I tried changing the tickformat by adding a function (like you have in d3)
but it seems plotly only accepts a string which it can interpret. 
Is there any other way in changing the tickformat?

I tried to set the tickvals to an array: [0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1] 
but still plotly changes this.

Help will be appreciated.

```js
var request = {
 "request": "getFloodScenarios",
 "success": true,
 "response": {
  "options": {
   "dataRows": [{
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk-1629077822",
    "name_calculation": "C-kering_Veluwerandmeren_zuidelijk_Flevoland_nulderdijk",
    "probability": "0.0008",
    "conditional_factor": "1.00",
    "waterDepth": "0.3108",
    "exceedance": "0.0013824"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk919981487",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_Stormopzet",
    "probability": "0.000396",
    "conditional_factor": "0.80",
    "waterDepth": "2.67",
    "exceedance": "0.0005824"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk-498661755",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_Stormopzet",
    "probability": "7.425E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.15",
    "waterDepth": "2.73",
    "exceedance": "0.0001864"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk-1427412338",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_Stormopzet",
    "probability": "2.475E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.05",
    "waterDepth": "2.79",
    "exceedance": "0.00011215"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk2017462865",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_meerpeil",
    "probability": "6.952E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.80",
    "waterDepth": "3.08",
    "exceedance": "8.74E-05"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk2090682125",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_meerpeil",
    "probability": "1.738E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.20",
    "waterDepth": "3.17",
    "exceedance": "1.788E-05"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "999",
    "geoserver_layer": " LBEO:Maximale_waterdiepte_NL",
    "name_calculation": "Maximale_waterdiepte_NL",
    "probability": "5E-07",
    "conditional_factor": "1.00",
    "waterDepth": "3.9746999740600586",
    "exceedance": "5.00000000000002E-07"
   }],
   "dikeRing": "8",
   "minExceedance": "5.00000000000002E-07"
  },
  "message": "Scenarios gevonden",
  "token": "7cdd9b03-5c18-4ec2-86dc-c46327fbdde3",
  "step": "report"
 }
};

var newToFixed = function (nr) {

 var arr1 = ("" + nr).split("e"),
   arr2 = [],
   fixedPos = null;

 //notation is already normalized
 if (arr1.length === 1) {
  return nr;
 }

 /**
    * remove the + or - from the number
    * now have the exact number digits we want to use in toFixed
    */
 if (arr1[1].indexOf("+") === 0) {
  arr2 = arr1[1].split("+");
 } else {
  arr2 = arr1[1].split("-");
 }

 //making sure it is a number and not a string
 //fixedPos = Number(arr2[1]);
 return nr.toFixed(arr2[1]);

};

var createTickSet = function(minVal, maxVal) {

 var that = this,
   minEx = parseFloat(Number(minVal).toPrecision()),
   maxEx = parseFloat(Number(maxVal).toPrecision());

 if (minEx > maxEx) {
  minEx = parseFloat(Number(maxVal).toPrecision());
  maxEx = parseFloat(Number(minVal).toPrecision());
 }

 var min = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(minEx))),
   max = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(maxEx))),
   tickMin = Math.floor(Math.log10(min)),
   tickMax = Math.ceil(Math.log10(max)),
   tickTotal = tickMax - tickMin,
   tickSet = [];

 for (var a = 0; a <= tickTotal; a += 1) {
  tickSet.push(newToFixed(Math.pow(10, tickMin)));
  tickMin += 1;
 }

 return {
  "min": min,
  "max": max,
  "tickMin": tickMin,
  "tickMax": tickMax,
  "tickTotal": tickTotal,
  "tickSet": tickSet
 };
};

var dataRows = request.response.options.dataRows,
  x = [],
    y = [],
  maxExceedance = dataRows[0].exceedance,
    minExceedance = dataRows[dataRows.length - 1].exceedance,
  tickData = createTickSet(minExceedance, maxExceedance),
  tickSet = tickData.tickSet,
  firstRow = $.extend(true, {}, dataRows[0]),
  lastRow = $.extend(true, {}, dataRows[dataRows.length - 1]);

console.log(tickData);

if (firstRow.waterDepth > 0) {
 firstRow.waterDepth = 0;
 dataRows.unshift(firstRow);
}

lastRow.exceedance = tickSet[0];
dataRows.push(lastRow);

for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i += 1) {
 for (keyName in dataRows[i]) {
  
  if (keyName == "waterDepth") {   
   x.push(dataRows[i].waterDepth);
  } 
  if (keyName == "exceedance") {
   y.push(dataRows[i].exceedance);
  }
 }
}

console.log(x);
console.log(y);

TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');

var line2015 = {
 x: x, 
 y: y,
 name: '2015',
 line: {
  shape: 'hv',
  width: 3,
  color: '#1f77b4'
 },
 marker: {
  size: 8
 }
};

var line2015_2 = {
 x: x, 
 y: y,
 hoverinfo: 'none',  
 name: 'onzekerheid',
 line: {
  shape: 'hv',
    width: 15,
  color: '#82bfe9'
 }
};


var line2050 = {
 x: x, 
 y: y,
 name: '2050',
 line: {
  shape: 'vh',
  dash: 'dash',
  color: '#b45c1f',
  width: 3
 },
 marker: {
  size: 8
 }
};

var layout = { 
      margin: { t: 15 }, 
  xaxis: {
   title: "Overstromingsdiepte in meter",
   tickmode: "linear"
  },
  yaxis: {
   title: "Kans per jaar",
   type: "log",
   tickvals: tickSet,
   dtick: 1,
   nticks: 10     
  }
   };

Plotly.plot( TESTER, [line2015_2, line2015, line2050], layout);

/* Current Plotly.js version */
console.log( Plotly.BUILD );
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>


<!-- Plots go in blank <div> elements. 
    You can size them in the plot layout,
    or give the div a size as shown here.
-->
<div id="tester" style="width:90%;height:250px;"></div>
```

Comment: You can make your **runnable** [mcve] here on site using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found several solutions.

in the axis where the '100μ' is found you can tell the axis not to use a format:

```
yaxis: {
    exponentformat: "none",
}
```

this way the 'μ' will not be used.

Another question answered is the 'function' I wanted to use like d3.
It is not possible. Though there is another option. 
As you can use 'tickvals' to give an array with the tick values you would like to use.

Next to the tickvals you can use ticktext, this will override the values in the tickvals. Per example:

```
yaxis: {
    tickvals: ['0', '1','2','3','4'],
    ticktext: ['A', 'B','C','D','E']
}
```

Now the yaxis will use the tickvals for the data, but in the text on the yaxis you will see A to E.

In my case I was using a logorithmic scale, which took some effort to get it right. As when you use 'yaxis.type=log' you will get into trouble using the tickvals and ticktext. As the log might override your settings.

My logorithmic scale was from 0.01 to 0.0000001 causing this to be shown on the scale. But I wanted 1/100 (which is equivalent to 0.01).

Eventually I used this:

```
yaxis: {
    title: 'kans per jaar', 
    type: "log",
    exponentformat: "none",
    tickvals: ["0.01", "0.001", "0.0001", "0.00001", "0.000001", "0.0000001"],
    ticktext: ["1/100", "1/1000", "1/10000", "1/100000", "1/1000000", "1/10000000"]
}
```

which worked for me as you can see here:

```js
var request = {
 "request": "getFloodScenarios",
 "success": true,
 "response": {
  "options": {
   "dataRows": [{
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk-1629077822",
    "name_calculation": "C-kering_Veluwerandmeren_zuidelijk_Flevoland_nulderdijk",
    "probability": "0.0008",
    "conditional_factor": "1.00",
    "waterDepth": "0.3108",
    "exceedance": "0.0013824"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk919981487",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_Stormopzet",
    "probability": "0.000396",
    "conditional_factor": "0.80",
    "waterDepth": "2.67",
    "exceedance": "0.0005824"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk-498661755",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_Stormopzet",
    "probability": "7.425E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.15",
    "waterDepth": "2.73",
    "exceedance": "0.0001864"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk-1427412338",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_Stormopzet",
    "probability": "2.475E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.05",
    "waterDepth": "2.79",
    "exceedance": "0.00011215"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk2017462865",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_meerpeil",
    "probability": "6.952E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.80",
    "waterDepth": "3.08",
    "exceedance": "8.74E-05"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "8",
    "geoserver_layer": "VNK:vnk2090682125",
    "name_calculation": "Almere_meerpeil",
    "probability": "1.738E-05",
    "conditional_factor": "0.20",
    "waterDepth": "3.17",
    "exceedance": "1.788E-05"
   }, {
    "dikering_nr": "999",
    "geoserver_layer": " LBEO:Maximale_waterdiepte_NL",
    "name_calculation": "Maximale_waterdiepte_NL",
    "probability": "5E-07",
    "conditional_factor": "1.00",
    "waterDepth": "3.9746999740600586",
    "exceedance": "5.00000000000002E-07"
   }],
   "dikeRing": "8",
   "minExceedance": "5.00000000000002E-07"
  },
  "message": "Scenarios gevonden",
  "token": "7cdd9b03-5c18-4ec2-86dc-c46327fbdde3",
  "step": "report"
 }
};

var newToFixed = function (nr) {

 var arr1 = ("" + nr).split("e"),
   arr2 = [],
   fixedPos = null;

 //notation is already normalized
 if (arr1.length === 1) {
  return nr;
 }

 /**
    * remove the + or - from the number
    * now have the exact number digits we want to use in toFixed
    */
 if (arr1[1].indexOf("+") === 0) {
  arr2 = arr1[1].split("+");
 } else {
  arr2 = arr1[1].split("-");
 }

 //making sure it is a number and not a string
 //fixedPos = Number(arr2[1]);
 return nr.toFixed(arr2[1]);

};

var createTickSet = function(minVal, maxVal) {

 var that = this,
   minEx = parseFloat(Number(minVal).toPrecision()),
   maxEx = parseFloat(Number(maxVal).toPrecision());

 if (minEx > maxEx) {
  minEx = parseFloat(Number(maxVal).toPrecision());
  maxEx = parseFloat(Number(minVal).toPrecision());
 }

 var min = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(minEx))),
   max = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(maxEx))),
   tickMin = Math.floor(Math.log10(min)),
   tickMax = Math.ceil(Math.log10(max)),
   tickTotal = tickMax - tickMin,
   tickSet = [];

 for (var a = 0; a <= tickTotal; a += 1) {
  tickSet.push(newToFixed(Math.pow(10, tickMin)).toString());
  tickMin += 1;
 }

 return {
  "min": min,
  "max": max,
  "tickMin": tickMin,
  "tickMax": tickMax,
  "tickTotal": tickTotal,
  "tickSet": tickSet
 };
};

var dataRows = request.response.options.dataRows,
  x = [],
    y = [],
  maxExceedance = dataRows[0].exceedance,
    minExceedance = dataRows[dataRows.length - 1].exceedance,
  tickData = createTickSet(minExceedance, maxExceedance),
  tickSet = tickData.tickSet,  
  firstRow = $.extend(true, {}, dataRows[0]),
  lastRow = $.extend(true, {}, dataRows[dataRows.length - 1]);

if (firstRow.waterDepth > 0) {
 firstRow.waterDepth = 0;
 dataRows.unshift(firstRow);
}

lastRow.exceedance = tickSet[0];
dataRows.push(lastRow);

for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i += 1) {
 for (keyName in dataRows[i]) {
  
  if (keyName == "waterDepth") {   
   x.push(dataRows[i].waterDepth);
  } 
  if (keyName == "exceedance") {
   var exc = Math.round(1/dataRows[i].exceedance);   
   y.push(dataRows[i].exceedance);
   //y.push(exc.toString());
  }
 }
}

var tickSet2 = [],
  tickText = [];

for (var u = 0; u < tickSet.length; u += 1) {
 var rounded = Math.round(1/tickSet[u]),   
   tickStr = '1/' + rounded;
 
 tickSet2.push(rounded.toString());
 tickText.push(tickStr);
}

console.log(y);
console.log(tickSet);
console.log(tickSet2);
console.log(tickText);

TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');

var line2015 = {
 x: x, 
 y: y,
 name: '2015',
 line: {
  shape: 'hv',
  width: 3,
  color: '#1f77b4'
 },
 marker: {
  size: 8
 }
};

var line2015_2 = {
 x: x, 
 y: y,
 hoverinfo: 'none',  
 name: 'onzekerheid',
 line: {
  shape: 'hv',
    width: 15,
  color: '#82bfe9'
 }
};


var line2050 = {
 x: x, 
 y: y,
 name: '2050',
 line: {
  shape: 'vh',
  dash: 'dash',
  color: '#b45c1f',
  width: 3
 },
 marker: {
  size: 8
 }
};

var data = [line2015_2, line2015, line2050];

var layout = { 
 height: 400,  
 margin: { t: 50, l: 125 },  
 xaxis: {
  title: "Overstromingsdiepte in meter",
  tickmode: "linear"
 },
 yaxis: {
  title: 'kans per jaar', 
  type: "log",
    exponentformat: "none",
  tickvals: ["0.01", "0.001", "0.0001", "0.00001", "0.000001", "0.0000001"],
  ticktext: ["1/100", "1/1000", "1/10000", "1/100000", "1/1000000", "1/10000000"]
 }, 
};

//Plotly.plot( TESTER, [line2015_2, line2015, line2050], layout);
Plotly.plot( TESTER, data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<!-- Plots go in blank <div> elements. 
    You can size them in the plot layout,
    or give the div a size as shown here.
-->
<div id="tester" style="width:90%;height:250px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Plotly uses [D3's format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format) for the axis ticks. You can overwrite the default settings by specifying [`tickformat`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickformat) in the layout settings, e.g.

```
{xaxis: {tickformat:'.7f'}}
```

would result in numbers with 7 digits after the dot.

```js
myPlot = document.getElementById('myPlot');
Plotly.plot(myPlot, [{
  x: [0.000001, 0.0000002],
  y: [1, 2]
}], {xaxis: {tickformat:'.7f'}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myPlot'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tickformat` should be the way to go. If you set that to `"r"` you should get what you want.

And you are right, the format of `tickformat` is in d3. `r` stands for "decimal notation, rounded to significant digits". That will get you your 0.0001 instead of 100μ. The documentation for d3 can be found here: https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#locale_format

Comment: thanks I tried that one and it didn't work. 
The 0.00001 for instance became 0.00001000000015 
don't know why....